# How to store a String in an Int Array?

Tags: java, string, multidimensional-array, int

I have a question. My teacher has asked as part of my assignment, to replace all 0's (zero's) with asterisk's (*'s) in my array.

This is an example of the output of my program:

```
Best Tour: #31
Number of Moves: 57
=====================================
 1   16   57    6    0   36   47    0   
56    7    0    3   46    5   32   37   
17    2   15    8   33   30   35   48   
14   55   22   45    4   49   38   31   
23   18   13   50    9   34   29   42   
54   51   24   21   44   41   26   39   
0    12   19   52   25   10   43   28   
0    53    0   11   20   27   40    0   
=====================================
```

Basically, everywhere there is a zero, he wants it to instead show an asterisk.
This is an int array. I have tried creating a String with the value " * ". Then I tried parsing it into an int, but I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "*"
```

Any other suggestions I should try out?

---

Thank you guys so much! I was just not looking at things correctly. After reading some comments, I realized that it didn't make much sense to try to change the zero's to asterisk's in the array itself.

So I modified my printArray() method, so that in any instance of 0, it will print *; else it just prints whatever number is supposed to be there.

Here is what it looks like now:

```
Best Tour: #45
Number of Moves: 58
=====================================
 1   42   13   18   31   44   27    *   
58   11   32   43   14   17   30   45   
41    2   57   12   19   26   15   28   
56   33   10    5   16   29   46    *   
 3   40   55   34    9   20   25   50   
 *   37    4   53    6   49   22   47   
39   54   35    8   21   24   51    *   
36    *   38    *   52    7   48   23   
=====================================
```

You all are so helpful, and very quick I might add! Thank you so much!

Comment: Hint: The array is a bunch int, the output is text. Where does an asterisk make most sense to be replaced? Numbers or text?

Comment: Advice: 1) Show the code you are using, 2) Always add a tag for the language you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't reliably store much of anything but ints in an array of ints, if you care about the values of the ints too.  (You could convert the char `*` to an int if you really really wanted to, but the ASCII code for it (42) would put it right there with potentially valid values for the ints, and cause you all kinds of grief later.)

So you have two realistic choices:

- Store strings instead of ints, convert everything to strings, and store `"*"` instead of `"0"`; or
- Only worry about the asterisks as you *output* the array, and wherever the value is 0, just output `"*"` instead.

The latter is far simpler, and leaves your ints as ints so you can still easily do math with them later if you want.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to put the asterisk inside the int array, focus on when you're outputting the area to the screen. Create a method to display the array like you have it formatted in the question, and when you're printing the numbers, be sure to check their values carefully.

*Note:* I'm not giving away the answer because this question is [homework](/questions/tagged/homework).

Answer (score 0):

You should deal with the `*`s when you are printing, not replace the `0`s with them in the array itself. Something like this (analogous method can be used in 2D-case):

```
int[] a = new int[]{1, 2, 0, 5, 9, 3, 0};
for (int i : a)
    // If ("a" is 0) then print "*", otherwise print "a"
```

Comment: i guess, he wanted to replace the array element itself not to print one

Answer (score 0):

FIRST: you cannot add String into int[] array.
so, you could do something like below.
as this a homework i dint write the whole code.

```
int[] x= {0,2,4,0,7};
String[] str= new String[x.length];
for(loop thru int array) {
    // check if the indexed element is equal to 0
    // if it is equal to 0 then add '*' into str
    // else add the number at the index into str
}
```

if you want to print them loop thru str[] and print each element

Answer (score -5):

i see there's 8 array, make sure to validate the array one by one if array contains zero, replace zero with *

Comment: Replacing * in an array of ints makes no sense.